# PHP: storing/displaying relative dates in UTC

Tags: php, timezone

I have a list of dates stored in MySQL using PHP.

These were stored using the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$strDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
```

I can only test this from my timezone, which is also UTC!

If a web visitor from eg Eastern Time USA views the page, will the date be converted to UTC correctly?

Presuming that I am storing the UTC dates correctly, what PHP function will display the UTC time, converted to the user's own timezone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're right to store the UTC; however remember that the date you have in PHP will be the server date - not the client date.

So to continue, read up on [how to extract timezone based dates](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#95834). Then consider [how to extract the timezone from the browser](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=139888) - which you will need if you do the local timezone output in PHP rather than on the client.